# Different templates for same content, landing page from different URLs (generic, simple)

Tags: templates, urls

I was wondering if anybody has a good idea how to solve this cheap.

Assume there are two urls:

- example.com/portfolio-xyz
- example.com/portfolios/someidentification

`example.com/portfolios/someidentification` shall display the content of: `example.com/portfolio-xyz` but using a different template.

Is there a way to archive this with minimum effort?

**EDIT**

The "landing page" (see above URls) in both cases is a WordPress `portfolio` custom post type page. So to say: no `page` and no `post` post type.

**additional information**

This shall not only work for one specific entry. It shall be generic for a set of portfolio postings.

So you have many portfolios on a website, and shall be able to access them via a differnt url/url-pattern (to the default url) and then have an other template displayed.

Comment: You'll need to be more specific than that. What are `portfolios` and `portfolio-xyz`. File an [edit] with this extra info

Comment: updated @PieterGoosen: does this help you?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What research have you completed? Have you read about the Template Hierarchy? http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy

Comment: You could also look at both the single_template and template_include filters

Comment: @helle This is not a forum, so your [edit]s do not only "help User X or Y", but should help anyone (incl. later readers) to understand your question easily. Questions and answers are references.

Comment: yes I know the hierarchy and do not think it has something todo with that. i am not new to wordpress ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what your definition of "simple" is, so not sure this qualifies. It's not really a simple task to do this dynamically.

First, we register a new query var to pass the alternate identifier:

```
function wpd_portfolios_query_var($query_vars){
    $query_vars[] = 'portfolio_key';
    return $query_vars;
}
add_filter('query_vars', 'wpd_portfolios_query_var');
```

Next, we add a rewrite rule to handle incoming requests, and set the query var accordingly:

```
function wpd_portfolios_rewrite(){
    add_rewrite_rule(
        'portfolios/([^/]+)/?$',
        'index.php?post_type=portfolio&portfolio_key=$matches[1]',
        'top'
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'wpd_portfolios_rewrite' );
```

Then we hook `parse_query`, check if our query var is set, and convert these requests to singular post requests. Otherwise WordPress will default to setting these requests to `is_home`.

```
function wpd_portfolios_parse( $query ){
    if( isset( $query->query_vars['portfolio_key'] ) ){
        $query->is_home = 0;
        $query->is_single = 1;
        $query->is_singular = 1;    
    }
}
add_action( 'parse_query', 'wpd_portfolios_parse' );
```

Next we hook `pre_get_posts` to set a meta query for the portfolio post with the desired meta value.

```
function wpd_portfolios_query( $query ){
    if( isset( $query->query_vars['portfolio_key'] ) ){
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 1 );
        $meta_query = array(
            array(
                'key' => 'portfolio_key',
                'value' => $query->query_vars['portfolio_key']
            )
        );
        $query->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpd_portfolios_query' );
```

And lastly, we filter `single_template` to load the special template for these requests:

```
function wpd_portfolios_template( $template = '' ){
    global $wp_query;
    if( isset( $wp_query->query_vars['portfolio_key'] ) ){
        $template = locate_template( 'portfolio-special.php', false );
    }
    return $template;
}
add_filter( 'single_template', 'wpd_portfolios_template' );
```

Answer (score 2):

The "cheapest" way to achieve this probably would be to simply add two pages:

```
// Standard template
http(s)://example.com/portfolio-xyz
```

Then add another page with your second URl and use a custom page template where you query your single post using [`get_post()`](http://queryposts.com/function/get_post/) and display it however it pleases you:

```
<?php
/* Template Name: Alternate Portfolio PT template */

get_header();

// Fetch post via ID
$post = get_post( 123 );
// Set everything up so the API is ready to use
$is_set_up = setup_postdata( $post );
if ( $is_set_up )
{
    the_title();
    the_content();
}

// or use a custom query
$post = new WP_Query( array( /* your arguments here */ ) );
if ( have_posts() )
{
    while ( have_posts )
    {
        the_post();
        the_title();
        the_content();
        // etc.
    }
}

get_sidebar();
get_footer();
```

Comment: so this is not very generic, but I like the idea. actually it shell work for not one specific posting.

Comment: Servus @helle "shell" is the "outer shell" and "shall" comes from "should" (fixed that in your question already) ;) - Please update your question to reflect the fact that you need a "generic and cheap" solution.